# Where does a wire labeled "3G" must be connected in turbo x notebook?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hard-drive

I got angry and punched my Turbo x notebook and it shutted down. When I opened it again I got the famous error 0xc00000e9. 
So I thought that possibly a cable is disconnected or the hard drive is displaced. 
I opened the case and I saw this cable:
[image]
[image]

It's labeled as 3G but I'm not sure if it has to be connected somewhere or not and if it was disconnected because of the punch.
I'm trying to make sure hardware is ok in order to procceed with the 0xc00000e9 error troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an antenna for an optional internal WAN (3G) modem card. Since you don’t have such a card, the wire stays disconnected.

Notice the M.2 slot under the cable? It also is marked ‘3G’ for the card.

Comment: Ok, clear. Thank you very much